# how to use single yii2 web application with different URL and databases

Tags: php, yii2

I want to use single yii2 web application with multiple databases and URLs.

Actually, I have a single web application on a single web server and I want to give subscription of it to different user/companies. Each company will have it's own separate database.
e.g.

```
company1 will want url xyz.com with database db1.
company2 will want url ab.xyz.com with database db2.
company3 will want url cd.xyz.com with database db3.
company4 will want url ef.xyz.com with database db4.
```

How can I implement the above scenario in yii2 web application?
Also the url should be in respect to the companies.(e.g. if company3 logins then url should be cd.xyz.com/login
if company4 wants to login then url should be ef.xyz.com/login and so on.)

Comment: where have you placed these configurations company, url and database ?
You can create multiple configuration file one per company. Based on sever URL include that file..
config/db/xyz.config.php
config/db/ab.config.php
....
You can include this in web/index.php
$config = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/main.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/main-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../config/main.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../config/main-local.php'),
require(__DIR__ . '/../config/db/xyz.config.php')
);

Answer (score 1):

You can create multiple database connections within 1 app, read [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#db-connection)
 and/or [this](http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/yii2-0-database-connection/).

In my opinion, managing which user connects to which database would be a mess. I would deploy 4 separate apps (or as many as you need), each with its own database. To mantain the code base, I would create some system or a script that updates the 'updatable' files in all apps at once: models, controllers, etc. but not config files, static resources, ...

Comment: Agreed. It is much simpler to maintain multiple instances of same app for different users rather than one big app with multiple connections. URL manager would be nightmare...